# Getting Image from Firebase Storage and placing into PDF

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, node-pdfkit

So i'm new to PDF kit and have a basic understanding of Javascript but i can't seem for the life of me to figure out how to place an image from Firebase Storage into the PDF or if there is a way to use GCF to store that image and place it into the PDF. I'm generating the PDF using Google Cloud Functions and Node.js Below is what i have so far:

```
exports.pdf = functions.https.onRequest((request,response)=>{
    //Create a document
    const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
    const doc = new PDFDocument();
    const storageBucket = admin.storage().bucket();
    const logo = g
    generateHeader(doc);
    // Pipe its output somewhere, like to a file or HTTP response
    // See below for browser usage

    // Embed a font, set the font size, and render some text
    doc.font('Courier')
       .fontSize(15)
       .text('Some text with an embedded font!', 100, 100);

    // Add an image, constrain it to a given size, and center it vertically and horizontally
    // doc.image('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/redog-bf9c8.appspot.com/o/pdfresource%2Fsplash.png?alt=media&token=25028ea2-5085-4782-9038-88b694b69f50', {
    //    fit: [250, 300],
    //    align: 'center',
    //    valign: 'center'
    // });

    // Add another page
    doc.addPage()
       .fontSize(25)
       .text('Here is some vector graphics...', 100, 100);

    // Draw a triangle
    doc.save()
       .moveTo(100, 150)
       .lineTo(100, 250)
       .lineTo(200, 250)
       .fill("#FF3300");

    // Apply some transforms and render an SVG path with the 'even-odd' fill rule
    doc.scale(0.6)
       .translate(470, -380)
       .path('M 250,75 L 323,301 131,161 369,161 177,301 z')
       .fill('red', 'even-odd')
       .restore();

    // Add some text with annotations
    doc.addPage()
       .fillColor("blue")
       .text('Here is a link!', 100, 100)
       .underline(100, 100, 160, 27, {color: "#0000FF"})
       .link(100, 100, 160, 27, 'http://google.com/');

    // Finalize PDF file
    const myPdfFile = admin.storage().bucket().file('/test/Arbeitsvertrag.pdf');
const stream = doc.pipe(myPdfFile.createWriteStream());
    doc.end();
    });

    function generateHeader(doc) {
        doc
          .image("storage/pdfresource/splash.png", 50, 45, { width: 50 })
          .fillColor("#444444")
          .fontSize(20)
          .text("ACME Inc.", 110, 57)
          .fontSize(10)
          .text("123 Main Street", 200, 65, { align: "right" })
          .text("New York, NY, 10025", 200, 80, { align: "right" })
          .moveDown();
      }
```

The issue i have is within the GenerateHeader function...it's staying it can't find the file...does anyone have any idea how i can point it in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here was to put the download url into a separate function:

```
  function toBase64(url) {
                return new Promise(async (resolve, reject)=>{
                    var https = require('https');
                    var req = await https.get(url, (res) => {
                        res.setEncoding('base64');
                        let body = "data:" + res.headers["content-type"] + ";base64,";
                        console.log("BODY", body)
                        res.on('data', (d) => {
                            body += d;
                        });
                        res.on('end', () => {
                            console.log("END", body)

                            resolve(body);
                        });
                    });
                    req.on('error', err => {
                        console.error('error!',err);
                        reject(err);
                    });

                });

            }
```

and then place it into your doc like so:

```
return Promise.all([toBase64(url)]).then(([base64])=>{
doc.image(base64,{width:50});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

*I am not exactly answering to your question, but here is a solution if you want to embed a **static** Image in you PDF, like for example a company logo.*

You can store the image within a folder under the `functions` folder and call it within your Cloud Function code.

For example, in your IDE, create a folder `images` under the `functions` folder, add the image `splash.png` under this folder and in your code call the image as follows:

```
  doc
    .image('./images/splash.png', 50, 45, { width: 50 })
    .fillColor('#444444')
    ....
```

Then re-deploy the Cloud Function and it should do the trick.

Comment: Brilliant that's actually one of the things i wanted to do but i also need the ability to pull it from Firebase storage (for other peoples company logos). i'll upvote because it's given me half the solution so thank you